# Как сделать, чтоб изображение в VideoView показывалось во весь экран?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть `VideoView` и когда я показываю в нем видео, то оно показывается на половину экрана... Я нашел несколько примеров как это делают, но в них тоже картинка в пол экрана... Сам элемент `VideoView` в `XML` имеет параметры `match_parent`. Я сначала подумал, что само качество видео не достаточное, поставил другое видео, но и они точно так же... Как сделать, чтоб видео показывалось на `Full screen`?

Answer (score 1):

Так попробуйте:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent" >
       <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoView"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </VideoView>
     </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: не помогает...  А у вас так работает?

Comment: На телефоне работало

Comment: загуглите еще: android manifest activity fullscreen notittle. Попробуйте в манифесте указать то, что будет советоваться

Comment: Я только, что подумал, что все дело в том, что само видео имеет такое соотношение сторон, что не может показываться в полный экран при вертикальном положении телефона...